# php - Uploading image works on localhost but not in server

Tags: php

I'm working on a class project, and I need a site where users can upload images, the problem is it is working in my WAMP server, but when I upload it to the remote server it doesn't work properly.

PHP file (upload.php)

```
<?php
$filename = 'img_' . uniqid() . '.jpg';
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($filename,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}

if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

if($uploadOk == 1){
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], "../img/grid/" . $filename);
echo "Upload correct";
}


?>
```

HTML form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```

I'm not sure what the error is, when I execute the upload, it shows the 'Upload correct message', but the image is not uploaded.

First time posting, sorry if I did something wrong, thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** The issue was the permissions. I went to the directory and executed the following command in the directory:

```
 chmod ugo+rwx
```

Comment: Is your remote server a windows server or linux.  What are the permissions on the directory '../img/grid/' on the server?  Did you look at the logs on the server to see if there are error messages.  I would bet there are, but most likely this is permissions issue.

Comment: It is a Linux server, the school provides it to us. Sorry but i'm not sure how to check/change permissions nor look into the logs

Comment: Does the directory even exist on the server?  To look at permissions you would use the ls command in a shell.  For the directory in question, the easiest answer is to make sure that it has rwx permissions.  So in the shell (and again I don't know what the exact path is on your server for that directory but you need to find that and make sure those directories exist).

Comment: You would (in the shell) do something like this:  chmod ugo+rwx /probably_path_to_your_home_dir/img/grid

Comment: You need to change permission of ```../img/grid/``` this folder in your linux server. Also you need to check that that folder exists or not. You have to set 777 permission to that folder.

Comment: Yes the folder exists, i actually have 'sample' images for display, and I'm trying to add new ones. Thanks for the answers I'll try to change permissions.